# Meaning of かけられる in the following sentence or context and its corresponding Kanji

Tags: meaning, kanji, passive-voice

Can any one please tell me what かけられる means in the following sentence and if it has any corresponding Kanji?

> 年明けの築地市場の初競りにかけられるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「年明{としあ}けの築地市場{つきじしじょう}の初競{はつぜ}りにかけられるのでしょうか。」

「かけられる」 here means "***to be put*** (up for auction)".

You might want to remember the set phrase 「競{せ}りに**かける**」("to put up for auction").  Its passive voice form is 「競りに**かけられる**」.

「かける」 for this meaning is most often written in ***kana***.  If you must use kanji for a good reason (though I have no idea what kind of reason that would be), it would be 「掛ける」.

> "I wonder if it is going to be put up for the first auction of the year at the Tsukiji Market."